# Blocks nested too deeply - Caused by virtual function

Tags: c++

I receive this error on the following code
`error C1061: compiler limit : blocks nested too deeply`
I don't have templates, I have 1 macro, 3 nested namespaces, and simple flat class as you can see below.
This class contains 225 data members, with a Get() function for each one.
When trying to compile this class alone, it works fine.
The error occurs when I use this object as a data member of another class in an exported dll.

I prefer not to use dynamic allocation as time is of utmost importance.
I need to use all my data members (which can be done with fewer but debugging would be harder), but I don't understand how this declaration of many arrays can affect this nested blocks.

**Things I've tried:**
Without the 'virtual' in the Get() functions, it compiles fine.
Actually, one Get() function with 'virtual' with 126 data members is enough to cause this problem.
Without the 'NATIVEDLL_API' macro in the class definition, it compiles fine.
When all arrays are pointers, it compiles fine.
MAX_SIZE macro value doesn't seems to be an issue in here.

**Calculator.h**

```
#ifdef CALCULATORDLL_EXPORTS
#define NATIVEDLL_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define NATIVEDLL_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif
#define MAX_SIZE 1000
class DataHelper
{
public:
    DataHelper(){}
    virtual double* GetPhase1(){return m_phase1;} // "virtual " cause error C1061
    virtual double* GetPhase2(){return m_phase2;} // "virtual " cause error C1061
    virtual double* GetPhase3(){return m_phase3;} // "virtual " cause error C1061
    ... more like those (225 in total)
    double m_phase1[MAX_SIZE];
    double m_phase2[MAX_SIZE];
    double m_phase3[MAX_SIZE];
    .... more like those (225 in total)
};


class NATIVEDLL_API Calcaultor          
{
    DataHelper m_staticData; 
}; // the error points to this line
```

Comment: You receeve *what* error?

Comment: I added the error to the message body too. it is the same as in the header.

Comment: You are sure you need that many members and getters? Why not simply using a 2-dimensional array?

Comment: Please post the exact code that gives the error

Comment: @SebastianStern I don't neccesarily need them, but it will make debugging much easier, and 2 dimensional array won't be helpful - as I need their names for that purpose.

Comment: @M.M I apologize, you might be right. the error occurs when I use this object as a data member of another object. I'll add it above....

Comment: You misunderstood the word *exact*. [Please read](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). And see if you can produce the error just using a single source file to make things easier

Comment: Thanks, I did misunderstood it :) I'll fix it shortly

Answer (score 0):

225 * 1000 * 8 = 1.7MB per instance of the class.   This is unlikely to fit on a normal stack.  If you use the heap instead of the stack, it should work, so why not change the class to:

```
DataHelper()
{
   m_phase1 = new double[MAX_SIZE];
   m_phase2 = new double[MAX_SIZE];
   m_phase3 = new double[MAX_SIZE];
}

double *m_phase1;
double *m_phase2;
double *m_phase3;
```

Don't forget to free them in the destructor.

Comment: Thanks, I don't wanna use dynamic allocation since it takes more time and I need to be efficient in this part of the code. Also, I tried to reduce the MAX_SIZE macro to 2 and it still throw this compiling error.